# Phonegap build cordova.js

Tags: javascript, build, cordova

I am developing Phonegap Build application. For the android file,when I try to compile the zip file, the APK file always contain 3 javascript file:phonegap.js cordova.js ... Yet the three files are of exactly the same content. How can I remove the two redundant js file in order to optimize my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI the reason the redundant files are present is to avoid user confusion [according to the devs](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/duplicates_in_apk_phonegap_js_cordova_js_cordova_x_x_x_js):

> Many users were including the wrong file. Allowing inclusion of any of
>   the above avoided a lot of confusion -- enough to outweigh the
>   footprint of two extra files, in our opinion.

Now that PhoneGap 2.8 introduced `cordova.js` without the version number in the filename, there is a [low-priority issue being tracked](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/147) to remove the redundant files (so if you just wait, it might be fixed soon on its own):

> Enhancement: PhoneGap 2.8 introduce cordova.js without version number.
>   Build could now exclude redundant .js files.

---

**But**, if you aren't willing to wait for them to upgrade the build process, you can remove the files yourself following these instructions:

**1**. Unpack the APK files into a local directory structure using `apktool` (you'll need the Android and Java SDKs installed on your machine) - [instructions here on how to unpack and remove files](http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/blog/2012/05/08/remove-unused-libraries-from-corona-apps/):

```
$ \path\to\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\apktool d myApp.apk
```

**2**. Remove the `phonegap.js` and `cordova-x.x.x.js` files (these are the unused ones in > 2.8.0).

**3**. Repackage the APK, again using `apktool`:

```
$ \path\to\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\apktool b myApp myAppUnsigned.apk
```

- note at this point that the APK isn't signed, and therefore can't be deployed to the Play Store or any devices which doesn't allow apps from unsigned sources.

**4**. Re-sign the APK file using your android cert so it's valid:

> Sign the apk using the jarsigner tool that’s part of the Java JDK.
>   You’ll also need your keystore and key alias that you used to sign the
>   app, as well as the password.

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore ~/MySigningKey.keystore ~/Desktop/myAppUnsigned.apk myKeyAlias

Enter Passphrase for keystore:
```

> After you enter your passphrase, you’ll see a whole bunch of ‘signing:’ messages zoom by; once it’s all done, you have a signed apk file.

**5**. The last step is to zipalign the apk file:

```
zipalign -v 4 myAppUnsigned.apk myApp.apk
```

And you should be done. You could automate all these steps into a batch/shell script for ease of use when building files.

Comment: Seems that even though I deleted Cordova.js, the file size is still big. Any other files that I could remove in order not to disturb the pack?

Comment: @SamuelCheung - you could try removing the splashscreen image files, any icons you won't need, and any native plugins you aren't using in your code using the same process. But that's kind of a different question altogether - if the steps in my answer worked for how to remove files, please mark it as the answer so the next person knows it works.

Comment: i am new to phonegap! which one do you includ in your index.html..phonegap.js or cordova.js

Comment: @MuhammadUmer phonegap.js

Comment: where do you include it (root)www\config.xml or www\xml\config.xml...sorry for bothering i know that root works best but why some examples tell you to do otherwise.